Is the Windows PID-assignment logic sequential or random?
I've been searching for some time, and I can't find any documentation about the windows PID-assignment logic. Are the PIDs assigned randomly? Sequentially? Randomly, but in sequential chunks?
For the last 3 months, I've been running a custom Node.js script. It is a crawling bot, to fetch data from my own API, with testing purposes (both performance and functional tests). The script creates 8 subprocess instances.
In the beginning, all the PIDs in the SO had 5 digits. But now, they are all 6-digit numbers. While searching, I saw many posts in stackoverflow explaining that this is pretty uncommon, but now, every single process has a PID over 500000, even ones like TaskManager (PID 541224 as I write this), WindowsExplorer (PID 523184) or WindowsDefenderSmartScreen (PID 574804).
Could someone tell me more about this?
It is abnormal, or normal behavior in Windows?
And is the PID assignment logic in Windows documented somehow?
This print was taken an hour ago:
Abnormally high PID values printed
I am starting to think that the PIDs are assigned randomly from pre-selected chunks. Every time I run the script, the new processes it creates are assigned 6-digit numbers, and in increasing value. Last month, I started to keep a track of this, and the smallest abnormal PID was 486204 (Antivirus container process) while the highest was 497600 (The "Service Host: Windows Time" process). Now they are ranging from 476808 ("Shell Infrastructure Host" process) to 574944 ("Runtime Broker" process).
I've seen this question thread, seems like high PIDs (over 250000) are very uncommon:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267284/forcing-a-high-pid-in-windows]
(I would like to apologise for my english, and for any question-based mistake. I am both a non-native speaker and a newcomer in the matter of asking questions in StackOverflow)

As far as I'm aware, process ID assignment is not documented. It's not anything to worry about.

Why exactly do you care what PIDs Windows assigns the process? It appears that any non-zero values that fit in a DWORD are legal based on the GetProcessId win32 function, this is the only guarantee you should assume.

@TimSweet. I am just genuinely curious about this Windows behaviour. I would like information about it if someone do know. And of course I am going to keep track of this for the next months, to check what will happen to this increasing PID situation. Maybe it will restart from 10-100 range? Maybe return to lower ones decreasing slowly? It is merely developer curiosity.
